# XCode: Frameworks - is there a plist of those included for a project

Tags: xcode, frameworks, applescript

Is there a plist or file that list all the frameworks included in an XCode project that can be accessed from outside of XCode (say by AppleScript)?

Thanks

Comment: Updated my answer to show one way to access the list without opening the project. and the file that has the file and framework list

Answer (score 1):

A quick example that returns the **frameworks** found in the *frameworks* group and its o*ther framework*s group

```
    set biglist to {}
tell application "Xcode"
    set my_proj to name of project of document 1
    set my_proj to (item 1 of my_proj)

    set rootGroop to (root group of project my_proj)
    set subGroup to groups of rootGroop whose name contains "Frameworks"


    set biglist to (name of file references of item 1 of subGroup)


    set otheFrameworksGroupRefs to (name of file references of groups of item 1 of subGroup)
    set otheFrameworksGroupRefs to item 1 of otheFrameworksGroupRefs
    repeat with i from 1 to number of items in otheFrameworksGroupRefs
        set this_item to item i of otheFrameworksGroupRefs
        copy this_item to end of biglist

    end repeat

end tell

biglist
```

---

There is also the Xcode command line tools that I suspect can do this, but I have not installed them so cannot test them.

[image]

---

**  **Update.**  *

To get the list without an open project:

In terminal.app I can use the 'cat' command  along with grep and awk to access project.pbxproj file which hold all the info you want

```
cat "/Users/FooUser/myProjects/fooApp/fooApp.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj"  | grep -i  ".framework\ \*\/\," | /usr/bin/awk '{print $3}'
```